# How can I get a Country Code from the Country Name in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocale

Say I have a country name like : "United States" and I want to convert it to "US". How do I do that?

I know how to do the opposite, but there doesn't seem to be a solution for this.

Comment: `[[NSLocale systemLocale] localeIdentifier];` holds it.

Comment: No. Let me modify this question. I don't want the system locale. I want to simply get a Country Code String from a Country Name String!